# remove firebase firestore query onSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Quick question regarding following code sample:

```js
firebase.firestore()
  .collection("chatrooms")
  .doc(`${chatId}`)
  .collection(`${chatId}`)
  .orderBy("timestamp")
  .limit(50).onSnapshot((snapshot)  => {
    //doing something with snapshot.val()
  })
```

I have setup that listener to my firestore and it is always only retrieving the 50 newest documents for me. My question would be: **If I want to detach this listener, can I do it this way?**:

```js
firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatId}`).collection(`${chatId}`).off();
```

Im asking because Im not sure if only calling `.off()` only on the reference allone works in this case. I know that it usualy does but I have my query ordered and limited so thats why Im asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any `off()` method on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#methods_1). The `onSnapshot` method returns a function which can be used to remove the listener *irrespective* of what the query was.

```js
const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore()
  .collection("chatrooms")
  .doc(`${chatId}`)
  .collection(`${chatId}`)
  .orderBy("timestamp")
  .limit(50).onSnapshot((snapshot)  => {
    //doing something with snapshot.val()
  })

// run this to remove listener
unsubscribe()
```

If you need to unsubscribe from listener from any other component, then you may have to pass this function using props.